# Column Summation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Pretty straight forward question. I have columns which I have already filtered to be of numerical type. What is the correct syntax for a summation query (add up all the elements in a given column).

I'm trying

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT column_name) FROM 'table_name' WHERE column_name = 'CN'
```

Where I replace table_name and CN with the appropriate values, but I get the error "invalid table name", but I know the table is valid so I assume my syntax is wrong.

Comment: `select sum(distinct column_name) from table_name`.  No single quotes.

Comment: In oracle the indentifer is the double quote,single quotes are for strings and dates.

Comment: Without the single quotes I get:  table or view does not exist

Comment: If you created your table with double quotes Oracle requires to always refer to it with double quotes.It thats the case just use double quotes.

Comment: looks like you are trying to sum up a `varchar` column. use `count` instead without single quotes around table_name

Comment: Table wasn't created with double quotes, and I've filtered columns by DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER'

Comment: Show us the table definition  ( the DDL )... and your full SQL statement, so that it is fully clear what you are working with.

Comment: If this query were working, wouldn't it **always return 1**? You filter by colum_name and make a distinct sum/count on it... actually you could just write SELECT SUM('CN')... ehm what are you trying to do?

Comment: this query will always return the value 1, could you please provide us some more information about your requirements

Comment: NVM, figured it out. Needed: select sum(CN) from schema.table_name

Comment: Figured Schema was involved.   This will help in the future :      ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=ownername  ;